# combining all the data into new sheet,excluding first sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have 4 sheets in my workbook . I want to combine all the data  in new worksheet . I got the code which I written below. But now I don't want to display sheet1 data in new sheet. Have attached the worksheet for your reference . Thanks in Advance!!!!

```
          sub Combine()
          Dim J As Integer
          On Error Resume Next
          Sheets(1).Select
          Worksheets.Add
          Sheets(1).Name = "Combined"
          Sheets(2).Activate
          Range("A1").EntireRow.Select
          Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A1")
          For J = 2 To Sheets.Count
          Sheets(J).Activate
          Range("A1").Select
          Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
          Selection.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1).Select
          Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp)(2)
          Next
          End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only minor changes to your code will make this work:

```
        Sub Combine()
          Dim Lastrow As Integer
          Dim J As Integer
          On Error Resume Next
          Sheets(1).Select
          Worksheets.Add
          Sheets(1).Name = "Combined"
          Sheets(3).Activate
          Range("A1").EntireRow.Select
          Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A1")
          For J = 3 To Sheets.Count
            Sheets(J).Activate
            ' First delete the empty rows
            Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Range("A2:L" & Lastrow).Select
            Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
            ' Then select the region as a table
            Range("A1").Select
            Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
            Selection.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1).Select
            Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp)(2)
          Next
        End Sub
```

Comment: Its a pleasure!

Comment: some of my worksheet has gap(1 or more empty rows) between the data .whereas the above code is taking only continues data . I need to combine entire data in my worksheet. kindly do the needful. Thanks!!

Comment: Hi, I edited the code to take into account the empty rows, basically select all data and delete empty rows, then select the data region (as table with header).

Comment: Its a pleasure!